# How to define that an attribute is optional?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm programming with SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I want to build in my program an optional attribute.

E.g

```
CREATE TABLE [Picture]
(
    Title VARCHAR(20),
    Signature VARCHAR(20),    <--- should be optional
    Alttext VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, it is by default "optional" -- if data for the `Signature` column is not provided, it will have a value of `null`.

However, to specify this explicitly (if, for instance, your database configuration is by default `NOT NULL`), the signature field could be expressed as so:

`Signature VARCHAR(20) NULL`

Comment: so when I add "NULL" it signalizes, that the value of the column is NULL (so there's nothing)? and for the attribute Signature to have some value the user have first enter something, right? my prof will ask questions and i just want to make sure my understanding of my command is right

Comment: @noclue123, the column definition in the `CREATE TABLE` DDL specifies whether the column allows NULL values or not.  The best practice is to explicitly specify either `NULL` or `NOT NULL` to avoid ambiguity of the current session settings.  When `NULL` is specified (the ANSI default), you can insert a new row with a NULL value explicitly by specifying value `NULL` or by omitting the column from the column and value list of the INSERT statement. A NULL value typically indicates UNKNOWN or not applicable.